# OAuth 2 Endpoint: Additional Fields?

Tags: rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

**Is is acceptable to include additional fields in an OAuth token endpoint response?**

For example, I am returning `UserId`, `Username` and `CompanyId` below:

```
{
    "access_token": "pHd4Wz1EF...",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 86399,
    "UserId": "7e7fbc39-8abd-41e1-b165-9d18b635b7a7",
    "Username": "user@somewhere.com",
    "CompanyId": "874f380a-76eb-49b1-81b5-a42100f7e4d0",
}
```

This essentially means that additional requests won't be necessary in order to get this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that - but a more standardized solution would be to use "OpenID Connect" for that purpose (see http://openid.net/connect/).

Comment: OpenID Connect would also give you login semantics so you can authenticate users with it. That may or may not be what you want to here, but just to be sure: the information returned from the token endpoint only provides details about the user on whose behalf the client (i.e. the application hat has the token) may act. It does not mean the the user (or more precisely the Resource Owner) is present or logged in.